# How does bash get commands into the operating system?

Tags: linux, bash

If I understand correctly, bash is just another user-land program.

So when I type:

```
ls -la
```

or

```
mv myfile.txt myotherfile.txt
```

how does bash feed these commands into the operating system kernel? Is this something to do with POSIX?

Comment: You know that `ls` and `mv` are programs too, right?

Comment: `man 2 fork` `man 2 execle`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, unless the command you enter into the command prompt is a [bash builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) (such as `cd`, `alias` or `echo`[1]) the shell will create a new process (using `fork(2)` syscall) and execute the program via the [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) system call.

[1] you can run `type something` to find out if `something` is a shell builtin